# Is there a syntatic sugar for ternary when you want only one outcome?

Tags: c#, ternary-operator, syntactic-sugar

In C#, many times I want to retrieve a string based on a expression. Most of the times I do this in the views.

So, for example, if I want to print "Complete" based on a boolean `isComplete`, I need to do this:

```
<span class="badge">@(isComplete? "Complete" : "")</span>
```

Is there any option in the language that would shorten this syntax, so I don't need to also have the empty string option?

Something like

```
<span class="badge">@(isComplete => "Complete")</span>
```

There are some ways to do this yourself, like a function that would receive a string and a boolean, and return null or empty if the boolean is false, but maybe it already exists in the language.

Comment: Although I do think this question will be closed for being "too broad" before someone with real answers can shed a light on this.

Comment: Makes no sense to me; not only is the savings minimal, it also seems dubious in terms of readabilty. Why would "" be the natural assignment instead of, say, no assignment? And of course for other data types other default values would apply. And for objects, what, null?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply declare a function like this:

```
public String GetTextOrEmpty( bool control, String text )
{
    return control? text : "";
}
```

And then invoke it like this:

```
<span class="badge">@(GetTextOrEmpty( isComplete, "Complete" ))</span>
```

Comment: Yep I tought of it like I said in the question. But a function is too obvious. Is there any way to extend an operator in order to do this?

Comment: I don't think so.  But let's see if anyone else has any ideas.

Comment: Let us hope. C# is a beautiful language full of syntatic sugars, it would really impress me if something like this don't yet exists.

Comment: @Phiter not currently. But you can convert the above to an extension method and call it directly on the bool value

Answer (score 0):

Not yet, but here are few alternatives:

`<span class="badge">@isComplete.Complete()</span>` - extension method

`<span class="badge">@Complete(isComplete)</span>` - method

`<span class="badge">@(Complete)isComplete</span>` - custom type with [explicit operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/explicit)

`<span class="badge">@isComplete</span>` - custom boolean type with [override ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method)